# BASH Syntax Checking Debug Mode Malfunction?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We can use `bash -n script.sh` to validate the syntax of a shell script. However, when I was trying to test this function, I noticed not all the syntax errors could be found by this option.

For example:

```
root@ubuntu:~/testenv# cat test 
#!/bin/bash
SEND=1
if [ "$SEND" -eq 0 ]
        echo no
fi
```

Now, let's test the script:

```
root@ubuntu:~/testenv# bash -n test 
test: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
test: line 5: `fi'
```

It works fine. However, if I just remove one of the bracket:

```
root@ubuntu:~/testenv# cat test     
#!/bin/bash
SEND=1
if [ "$SEND" -eq 0 
then 
        echo no
fi
root@ubuntu:~/testenv# bash -n test 
root@ubuntu:~/testenv#
```

Nothing happened!

I also checked the man page of bash, it describes the "-n" is:

```
 -n               Read  commands  but  do not execute them.  This may be used to check a
                  shell script for  syntax  errors.   This  is  ignored  by  interactive
                  shells.
```

It is a script file, so it shouldn't be an "interactive shell" right? So,how could this happen?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @NeilWang: Looks valid! Do highlight the same, people may mis-interpret it

Comment: @Inian In the second example, I missed a close bracket "]", but the syntax checker didn't find! Please execute them on your own box, you will find it will throw an error.

Comment: @NeilWang: You can't expect to catch that error, it ain't a syntax violation, `[` is a shell built-in

Comment: @Inian All right, so it can't find every single error in a script, rather than "perl -c".

Comment: Would you expect it to find the error in `if sed 's/too/many/delimeters/g'; then echo foo; fi` ?  The error in your sample is of the same type; the error is not a syntax error.

Comment: This is an excellent example to demonstrate that `[` is *not* part of the shell grammar, but merely a command.

Comment: This is a good question, why do people want to close it and downvoted it?

Comment: Just a comment for OP: you should not run stuff like this as root!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks for the advice, because of it is my virtual machine, so I often do it casually ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you have run into a very strange quirk of the way the shell implements single-bracketed conditionals: `[` is a *command*, not a special character. Look in your system executable directory (probably `/usr/bin`) and you will find an executable file literally named `[` which implements this command. When you write something like

```
[ "$SEND" -eq 0 ]
```

then you're actually invoking the command `[` with four arguments:

1. The value of `$SEND`
2. The string `-eq`
3. The string `0`
4. The string `]`

The command `[` checks that the last argument is `]` (because it would look weird otherwise), then puts the remaining arguments together to form a condition and return the result of testing the condition.

Now, because `[` is a command, it's not a syntax error to invoke that command with any set of arguments you like. Sure, if you leave off the trailing `]`, you will get an error, but that error comes from the command `[`, *not* from the shell. That means you have to actually run the script to get the error - the syntax checker won't see anything wrong with it. As far as bash is concerned, `[` is just a command name, no different from, say, `my_custom_conditional_test`, and if you were to write

```
my_custom_conditional_test "$SEND" -eq 0
```

it would be obvious that this is fine, right? Bash thinks of `[` the same way.

I should note that for efficiency, bash doesn't actually *use* the executable file `/usr/bin/[`; it has its own builtin implementation of `[`. But people expect `[` to act the same way regardless of whether it's built in to the shell or not, so the Bash syntax checker can't give its own `[` special treatment. Since it wouldn't be a syntax error to invoke `/usr/bin/[` with no trailing `]`, it can't be a syntax error to invoke the builtin `[` without a `]`.

You can contrast this with `[[`, which does more or less the same thing (testing a condition) but *is* given special meaning by the shell. `[[` is a special token in shell syntax, not a command. If you write `[[` instead of `[`, and you omit the corresponding trailing `]]`, you bet Bash is going to complain about a syntax error.

Comment: You are exactly damn right! I had never known there is a `[` under `/usr/bin`. Thank you for solving my concerns.